# How to import a very large .sql file into a sqlite3 database in Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, file-handling

I have a .sql file with a size of almost 400,000 kb. When I try to open and then read it, Python just stops at the line where I have the read() function written and throws a MemoryError. Now, I would read it by line but the .sql file is not written such that each line contains just 1 statement. Some of those statements continue on the next line, too. I would then also just edit the .sql file according to my liking but all the editors I have load it way too slow and eventually crash because the file is just THAT BIG. I am new to Python so I'm not familiar with file processing in this language. Any suggestions before I resort to manually copy-pasting each sql statement found in the file?

Comment: This should help https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite

Comment: Read the entire file into a single string/byte array (prehaps using mmap?) and use the `executescript()` method. Or skip python and just use the sqlite3 shell program's `.read` command instead: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html